# Finding position of 2D point constrained by "parent" point constrained to circle and rotation

Tags: geometry, circles, constraints, quadrilateral

I have the following 2D geometry question from a camera positioning problem:

Point $P1$ (parent) can only be on a circle about the origin with given radius $R$. Point $P2$ (child)'s position is calculated by moving (given) $d_r$ distance from parent in a direction outwards from the origin and (given) distance $d_t$ tangent to the circle at the position $P1$ is at.

The question is, given any point in the Cartesian plane, say $P3$, where should I place $P1$ along the circle such that the line drawn between $P3$ and $P2$ is parallel to the line between the origin and $P1$?

Below is a picture that should help hopefully!

[image]

Comment: Is $d_r$ directed along $OP_1$?

Comment: yes, it is -- i just drew $d_r$ and $d_t$ combined into one vector $d$ in the diagram

Comment: Just place $P_1$ so that $|\vec{OP_1}\times\vec{OP_3}|=Rd_t$.

Comment: Since its not immediately obvious to me, could you please explain why this is true :)

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\theta=\angle P_1OP_3$ then $OP_3\sin\theta$ is the distance between $P_3$ and line $OP_1$, and $d_t$ is the distance between $P_2$ and line $OP_1$.
If $P_2P_3$ is parallel to $OP_1$ then those distances are equal, so that:
$$
\sin\theta={d_t\over OP_3}.
$$
Of course there are two possible choices for $\theta$, depending on $\angle P_1OP_3$ being acute or obtuse. The right choice must take into account the direction of $d_t$. If $d_t$ is drawn counterclockwise (as in the diagram above), then the obtuse solution must be taken.

Comment: How does one get $P1$ once knowing $\theta$? Just do some vertical angle stuff right? Also, thank you!!

Comment: It depends on your setting. Do you have the coordinates of $O$ and $P_3$ and want the coordinates of $P_1$?

Comment: Yeah, $O$ and $P_3$ are known so it is definitely possible! Thanks again!